# Migrating existing cakephp 3.0 database to postgres from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, cakephp

I am in the process of migrating a cakephp 3.0 database from mysql to postgress. I used [this](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/FromMySqlToPostgreSql) tool for the database migration and it worked beautifully. After that I changed the config file as shown below.

```
  'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '5432',
            'username' => 'postgres',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'database' => 'cake_bookmarks',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        ],
```

The root folder in localhost also shows "successfully connected to database". However when i run my application, it shows an error:

> Cannot describe *mytable*. It has 0 columns. Cake\Database\Exception

I can't make sure if this is because of not connecting to the database (which i think is unlikely as the root page shows as connected) or cakephp being unable to use my database.
If so, how can I fix the issue. I am quite new to cakephp too, just confguring and doing basic stuff.

Comment: Could you add which CakePHP version you're using?

Comment: 3,0 ,I'll update the question

Comment: Seems like you do not have the table in your database. I would suggest checking that the table is there, the database user has permissions for reading it and that you configured the right schema in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (test after each step):

- Check if the table is present in the database
- Check if the expected columns are defined into the table
- Clear the Cake cache (if is FileCache is enough to delete files under `tmp/cache/persistent` `tmp/cache/models` and `tmp/cache/views`
- Check the permissions of the specific user on the database `cake_bookmarks` (maybe via phppgadmin)

Hope to help!